# Rotate a matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this type Mat `a = [[a]]` to represent a matrix in haskell.
I have to write a function which rotate a matrix, for e.g `[[1,2,3],[0,4,5]`,`[0,0,6]]` will become `[[3,5,6],[2,4,0],[1,0,0]]` so I made this:

```
rotateLeft :: Mat a->Mat a
rotateLeft [[]] = []
rotateLeft (h:t) = (map last (h:t)):(rotateLeft (map init (h:t)))
```

but the output is

```
[[3,5,6],[2,4,0],[1,0,0],[*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```

I don't know what to put in the base case to avoid this exception. 
Apreciate any help.

Comment: After you fix your function up, you might like to think about how you could build this out of existing functions and without explicit recursion. (Spoilers: base64 decode `cm90YXRlTGVmdCA9IHJldmVyc2UgLiB0cmFuc3Bvc2UK`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list won't be empty but a list of empty lists, you can do the following to pattern match based on the first sublist (assuming Mat ensures data structure consistency)

```
rl [] = []
rl ([]:_) = []
rl m = map last m : (rl (map init m))

rl mat
[[3,5,6],[2,4,0],[1,0,0]]
```

You're missing the second case.

Answer (score 9):

I'm an old man in a hurry. I'd do it like this (importing `Data.List`)

```
rotl :: [[x]] -> [[x]]
rotl = transpose . map reverse
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest solution would be:

```
import Data.List

rotateLeft :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotateLeft = reverse . transpose

rotateRight :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotateRight = transpose . reverse
```

Data.List is a standard module.

transpose slices rows into columns, which is almost like rotating, but leaves the columns in the wrong order, so we just reverse them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your pattern isn't matching. Stepping through what your code does, we start with:

```hs
Prelude> let x = [[1,2,3],[0,4,5],[0,0,6]]
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> map last x
[3,5,6]
Prelude Data.List> let y = map init x
Prelude Data.List> y
[[1,2],[0,4],[0,0]]
Prelude Data.List> map last y
[2,4,0]
Prelude Data.List> let z = map init y
Prelude Data.List> z
[[1],[0],[0]]
Prelude Data.List> map last z
[1,0,0]
Prelude Data.List> map init z
[[],[],[]]
```

So the basic problem is that your base case you're matching on is not `[[],[],[]]` but is instead `[[]]`, so that pattern doesn't match.

You now have more or less three options: you can (a) try to terminate when the first empty list is seen; this is written in Haskell as `any null`, using the `any` function and the `null` function, both defined in the Prelude; or (b) you can hardcode that this only works for 3x3 matrices, and just match against `[[],[],[]]`, or (c) you can try to terminate when all lists are empty (`all null`), in which case you can either skip elements that don't exist or wrap everything in the `Maybe x` datatype, so that missing elements are represented by `Nothing` while present elements are represented by `Just x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rotateLeft []     = []
rotateLeft ([]:_) = []
rotateLeft (h:t)  = (map last (h:t)):(rotateLeft (map init (h:t)))
```

The first pattern is for the case when the head of the list of lists is longer than other elements.

You got the second pattern wrong: if we have a proper matrix (ie elements are of the same length), then the base case is a list of empty lists. However, you wrote [[]], which is only true if the initial list consists of a single list.